# ProgressBar using AsyncTask and working on GoogleMap object

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar, google-maps-android-api-2

I used an AsyncTask to retrieve data from db (in doOnBackground()), and prepare it to show to the user. During these operation the ProgressBar spin perfectly.

When i need to operate on the object GoogleMap to draw Polylines, Markers, and so on, all this job is done by onPostExecute(), and the ProgressBar stop to spin.

**There is a way to operate on "GoogleMap" and let the ProgressBar to spin so the user is informed the app is working yet ?**

Thanks

Comment: Show ProgressDialog in onPreExecute() method of AsyncTask and Finish Dialog in onPostExecute().. do your all task in doInBackground()..

Comment: Can i operate on GoogleMap object from doOnBackground() without break the rule "Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread" ?

Comment: whats your error? where do you stuck ?

Comment: @Heshan Sandeepa no error, i'm asking if there is a way to update the GoogleMap object (an update that needs some seconds) while the ProgressBar continue to spin.

Answer (score 0):

Define a local Progress class which can hold all the information you need for your map update. Then you can publish the progress one by one and update the map in onProgressUpdate.
OnProgressUpdate is not limited to update the progress bar only.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work, because in the doOnBackground() there is a For{} cicle to add all the Polylines, Markers, ... and every time it calls onProgressUpdate(), this needs some times to update the object GoogleMap, meanwhile the For{} cicle in the doOnBackground() continue to run. At the end i have only few updates in the object GoogleMap.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think you can hold a synchronized queue in your doOnBackground, in which you push the information. Then pass this queue to the onProgressUpdate (using your local Progress class). If you use a BlockingQueue make sure, you do not try to poll from the empty queue in the UI-Thread however !

Comment: I tried something like this, every time i call publishProgress() (because the for cicle in the doOnBackground go on by 1 step) i set up a boolean check to false so the cicle in doOnBackground cannot go on till this check is true. It is true when onProgressUpdate() finish its job. It works, but not so good beacuse instead of some secs compute, it needs mw more then 80 secs. Pity. For now i use with the spin blocked (or with a message that doesn't need to spin).

Comment: Why do you stop in doOnBackground? By that you are of course serializing the two tasks, and both times will sum up. For concurrent work, the doOnBackground-method should continuously push into the queue and publish it and onProgressUpdate should pull from the queue and draw it.